# Can any one tell me how to set NSPredicate for NSArray having NSDictionary in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nspredicate

I have Structure as :

```
[
 {
  "time": {
    "td": 3036
  },
   "creditCardType": {
     "cardType": "MasterCard",
     "default": false
   },
   "transactionid": {
     "transactionReferenceNo": "xyz",
     "amount": 11.62,
     "transactionStatus": "SUCCESS"
   }
 },
 {
   "time": {
     "td": 3037
   },
   "creditCardType": {
     "cardType": "MasterCard",
     "default": false
   },
   "transactionid": {
     "transactionReferenceNo": "xyp",
     "amount": 13.62,
     "transactionStatus": "SUCCESS"
   }
  }
]
```

in this i have to remove duplicates with respect to `transactionReferenceNo`, for that i set Predicate is as:

```
NSDictionary *transactionDict = [dict valueForKey:@"transactionid"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"transactionid", @"transactionReferenceNo",[transactionDict valueForKey:@"transactionReferenceNo"]];`
```

this will crashes my app and gives me error:

```
The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.
```

what wrong m doing..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arr = @[
                 @{
                     @"time": @{
                         @"td": @3036
                     },
                     @"creditCardType": @{
                         @"cardType": @"MasterCard",
                         @"default": @NO
                     },
                     @"transactionid": @{
                         @"transactionReferenceNo": @"xyz",
                         @"amount": @(11.62),
                         @"transactionStatus": @"SUCCESS"
                     }
                 },
                 @{
                     @"time": @{
                         @"td": @3037
                     },
                     @"creditCardType": @{
                         @"cardType": @"MasterCard",
                         @"default": @NO
                     },
                     @"transactionid": @{
                         @"transactionReferenceNo": @"xyp",
                         @"amount": @(13.62),
                         @"transactionStatus": @"SUCCESS"
                     }
                 }
                 ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"transactionid.transactionReferenceNo CONTAINS[c] %@",
                          @"xyp"];

NSArray *arr2 = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"arr2 = %@", arr2);
```

In your case the predicate should be like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"transactionid.transactionReferenceNo CONTAINS[c] %@",
                          transactionDict[@"transactionReferenceNo"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"transactionid %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"transactionid", @"transactionReferenceNo",[transactionDict valueForKey:@"transactionReferenceNo"]];
```